# How to create graph in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to add a line graph in a fragment but I fail. How can I do it?

Here is my fragment code:

```
public class Info extends Fragment 
{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);

    GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0, 1),
            new DataPoint(1, 5),
            new DataPoint(2, 3),
            new DataPoint(3, 2),
            new DataPoint(4, 6)
    });
    graph.addSeries(series);
}

}
```

and when i try to run i am getting this error:
        GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
Error:(42, 39) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

I also have this in my info.xml

```
 <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:id="@+id/graph" />
```

but still geting error.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you please explain more about what is going on, what you're trying to do, and what isn't working specifically?

Comment: ı am getting error for this       GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
Error:(42, 39) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

Comment: Can you edit your question and add that error to it?

Comment: use this https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4978

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 3:** I misread your error message. I apologize. Your error message is saying it can't find the method findViewById on the Fragment. This is because Fragments do not have this method, only Activities do. You must get a reference to your inflated view and then call view.findViewById(R.id.graph), like in the following code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);
    GraphView graph = (GraphView) view.findViewById(R.id.graph);
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new 
        DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0, 1),
            new DataPoint(1, 5),
            new DataPoint(2, 3),
            new DataPoint(3, 2),
            new DataPoint(4, 6)
    });
    graph.addSeries(series);
    return view;
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** Move your return statement to the end of your method. Like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new 
        DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0, 1),
            new DataPoint(1, 5),
            new DataPoint(2, 3),
            new DataPoint(3, 2),
            new DataPoint(4, 6)
    });
    graph.addSeries(series);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);
}
```

---

**UPDATE 1:** According to your updated question, your code shows that you are returning from inside your `onCreateView` before you set your graph with your data. In fact, you shouldn't be getting the error you're getting since that code never gets reached. This is the code I'm referring to:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);

    GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new 
        DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0, 1),
            new DataPoint(1, 5),
            new DataPoint(2, 3),
            new DataPoint(3, 2),
            new DataPoint(4, 6)
    });
    graph.addSeries(series);
}
```

---

In the comments of your question, you said you're getting

```
 GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph); Error:(42, 39) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
```

This means your layout doesn't have a control with an android:id of `graph`. Check your layout and make sure you have a control with `android:id="@+id/graph"` as an attribute.

Comment: ı have it  <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:id="@+id/graph" />

Comment: so what should i do i didn't understand ::S

Comment: See my UPDATE 2.

Comment: it is stil same cannot resolve method findviewbyid(int)... should i use something like getview maybe ? btw i also tried getview().findviewbyid too

Comment: I misread your error message. I've updated my answer. That should 100% fix it

Comment: thanks. btw i have 1 more question i want to add expandable viewpager in a fragment. when i click on of the images i want too see the  fullscreen image with zoom option is it possible ?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible with enough time and effort.

Comment: 1 more thing i want to show 12 months temperature with this graph but when i add 12 lines i can see only 8 of them. why is it ?

Comment: I don't know. I have never used this charting solution. Also this is now the second "one more" question :P